# What font is this?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Anyone know what is the below font name ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Vivaldi](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/vivaldi/), but the top line's been artificially compressed, by the look of it. The font comes standard in Windows and Mac OS, from what I recall.

Comment: thanks, that's it! You're right about the compression. That was throwing me off. Thank you!